# Neo4J data modelling

Tags: data-structures, neo4j, graph-databases

I have an use case. A `product_combo` is `sold_at` two or more `store`s at different `price`. And each store is mapped to a `state`.
How can I structure this scenario.

Please find the relation as in below structure.

```
Store{name:"Store 1"} -[:LOCATED_IN]-> State{name:"AZ"}
Store{name:"Store 2"} -[:LOCATED_IN]-> State{name:"MO"}
Store{name:"Store 1"} -[:SELLS]-> ComboPack{name:"Combo1"}
Store{name:"Store 2"} -[:SELLS]-> ComboPack{name:"Combo1"}
ComboPack{name:"Combo1"} -[:CONTAINS]-> Product{name:"Prod 1"}
ComboPack{name:"Combo1"} -[:CONTAINS]-> Product{name:"Prod 2"}
```

I want to know how can i place the link in such a way that the price for each prod is determined in product level at different store/state.

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZ42.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the price as a property for `[:CONTAINS]` relationship.

The total price of a `Combo` should be placed as a property for that `ComboPack` node as well (here you duplicate the data to exchange for faster `sum` query)

**Update**

As your requirement, you should break the relationship `Store -[]-> Combo` to smaller part.

One way is to introduce SpecificCombo node:

```
(:Store)-[:SELLS]->(:SpecificCombo)-[:IS_A]->(:Combo)
(Combo)-[:CONTAINS]->(Product)
(:SpecificCombo)-[:INCLUDE {price: 15$}]->(Product)
```

Comment: Thanks!

But my situation is as below:
The prods are sold at the below prices in `State:AZ`
`Prod 1` is `$20`
`Prod 2` is `$10`
And sold at the below prices in `State:MO`
`Prod 1` is `$25`
`Prod 2` is `$15`

Is there a possibility to tackle this situation?